# How to Parse a query in Azure Data Studio?

Tags: ssms, azure-data-studio

In Sql Server Management Studio, we can click a "Parse" button (or Ctrl+F5) to verify that a SQL statement is syntactically correct (without executing it).

How can I do it the same in Azure Data Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no key mapped but you can map it.

Go to:
File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts
or 
Ctrl+K Ctrl+S

Use the search feature or scroll down to "Parse Query" and setup a key binding

[image]